# printing page mode in epson tm-t88v

Tags: objective-c, ios, printing, epson

Does any one how to center text to be printed using page mode in ePOS ios SDK?

this is my code

```
int retVal = success;

retVal = [builder addPageBegin];
retVal = [builder addText:@"Text"];
retVal = [builder addPageEnd];
```

But it doesn't work and doesn't print. any ideas? thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can send commands to the printer to set the page format.
For instance, to center a text, you can use : ESC a 1

Comment: That doesn't work, once page mode is specified you have to manually specify the position :(